# Limesurvey RC2 API get all the answers for questions

Tags: c#, json.net, limesurvey

I want to get all the responses for a survey. I found RC2 method 'export_responses' but it only have information about answers those have responses. In my tool I want to display zero responses for answers those are not having responses.

So then I might need to get all the answers for question. I search for document and found "get_question_properties" method. ref http://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_get_question_properties

I assume that I can get all the answers for question by setting appropriate value for 'aQuestionSettings' here. Above doc specified 'aQuestionSettings' as an array but I am not sure how to pass an array for that method.

My client program is in c# based on 'Newtonsoft JSON'. So please suggest a better way of getting all the answers for an questions or please help on calling "get_question_properties" method with parameter "aQuestionSettings" with c# or java client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array as follows,

```
JArray.Parse(@"['gid', 'type', 'answeroptions']")
```

Answer (score 0):

export_responses with $sCompletionStatus to 'all' give you all the response in JSON format.